# How can I produce a separate output file for each entity named in a regular expression?

Tags: google-bigquery

I ran this code:

```
SELECT theme, COUNT(*) as count
FROM (
select UNIQUE(REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(V2locations,';'), r',.*', '')) theme
  from [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg]
where DATE>20150302000000 and DATE < 20200609000000 and REGEXP_MATCH(V2locations, 
r'Burundi|Djibouti|Egypt|Equatorial Guinea|Eritrea|Mauritania|Sierra Leone|South Sudan|PR Congo|DR 
Congo|Guinea Bissau|Sao Tome and Principe')   
AND V2themes like '%WB_133_INFORMATION_AND_COMMUNICATION_TECHNOLOGIES%'
)
group by theme
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 300
```

I would like to produce separate output files listing the themes for each of the countries.  How can I do this?

Comment: when you say "file" - do you mean export to file in gcs? or you mean separate output tables or something else?  please elaborate

Comment: The search produces a CSV file containing rows for each theme and a column of counts.  I need to generate this output file for each country (n=53).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to achieve, what your expected results are and if you using the console? So I can understand better and properly help you.

Comment: I am analyzing the themes associated with ICT in 54 African countries.  I need to produce counts of the themes co-occurring with the ICT theme for each country.  If I run a separate query for each country the costs are very high, so I am trying to somehow embed all 54 searches into a single query because as I understand it, the costs are not based on search time but on the size of the database searched, which is 1.4 terabytes.